# Need cache-busting on CSS file in Blazor WebAssembly site

Tags: browser-cache, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM .NET6 application, which uses two stylesheets in its index.html:

```
<link href="css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/Client.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

How to add some version number or date to the file on build, like:

```
<link href="css/app.min.20211119.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/Client.min.20211119.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to trigger the browser to download a fresh copy?

I already have PostCSS setup in my build pipeline, so an npm solution is fine by me.

It needs to create new files AND update the index.html

I've found several similar questions but none of them have a working solution.

**Update**:
I found the [Replace in file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) npm package, which seems to do what I need. Combining it with the [fs.rename](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) npm package I should be able to add a fingerprint to my file name and change the link in my index.html.
I already figured out how to do this for the links in index.html:

```json
// in package.json
"fingerprint": "replace-in-file --configFile=fingerprint.config.js"

// in fingerprint.config.js
module.exports = {
    files: 'wwwroot/index.html',
    from: [/app.(min|[0-9]*).css/g, /Client.(min|[0-9]*).css/g],
    to: ['app.' + require('dayjs')().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm') + '.css', 'Client.' + require('dayjs')().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm') + '.css'],
};
```

This piece of code is run in the postbuild, so nothing of this javascript ends up in the final code.

I tried all day to rename the actual CSS file. But can't get it to work.
My tries:

```json
// In package.json
    "rename:fs": "node -e \"require('fs').rename('wwwroot/css/app.min.css', 'wwwroot/css/app.'+require('dayjs')().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm')+'.css', () => {})\"",
    "rename:2": "renamer --dry-run --find \"/^(app|Client).(min|[0-9]*).css$/\" --replace \"$1.bar.css\" \"wwwroot/css/*\"",
    "rename": "node -e rename.js"

// rename.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
//var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var dir = "wwwroot/css/";
var match = RegExp("^(app|Client).(min|[0-9]*).css$", 'g');
var fp = require('dayjs')().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm');
var replace = RegExp('$1.' + fp + '.css');
var files;

//reading the dir
files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
files.filter(function (file) {
    return file.match(match);
}).forEach(function (file) {
    var filePath = path.join(dir, file),
        newFilePath = path.join(dir, file.replace(match, replace));
    //using fs.rename function to rename files
    fs.renameSync(filePath, newFilePath);
});
```

The renamer version `rename:2` is working best. I can use RegEx in the find part but can't get it to work in the replace part.
For now I'll stick with the changing of the query string, not the solution I was aiming for. But good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

During development, I use this javascript work around.
It should be me removed and replaced with your original markup for production, especially as you're probably trying to avoid javascript in a webassembly app.

```
let dt=new Date();
const lnk=document.createElement('link');
lnk.setAttribute('href','css/app.min.css?u='+dt.getTime());
lnk.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appandChild('lnk');
```

The unique querystring on the CSS file is forces the browser to get a new copy but the application just ignores the extra data.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer might be, add the css tags in the web assembly:

```
<link href="css/@(myawesomeappcss)" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/@(myawesomeclientcss)" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Then use the following:

```
@code
{
  private string myawesomeappcss = "app.min.css?u=";
  private string myawesomeclientcss = "client.min.css?u=";

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    DateTime dt= DateTime.Now;
    myawesomeappcss += ((DateTimeOffset)dt).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(1);
    myawesomeclientcss += ((DateTimeOffset)dt).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
  }
}
```

Although, the javascript version would be easier to remove before publishing.

Comment: I don't want to remove it before publishing. For my users the latest CSS files need to be downloaded as well.   
I'm on the `index.html`. Can I also use Blazor code in that file?  
And I understood adding a query string is not enough. The file name should be changed.

Comment: You can't use c# code in an html file.
You could change the hosting site from a static thml page to a .Net Razor page  quite easily, then use c# to alter the <link  href> attribute. You'd still need to change the file name on deployment, which could possibly be done with Node.js when the CSS gets minified.